# Banco de Dados Inner Join

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server

Pessoal estou utilizando esse comando no sqlserver:

```
SELECT ALUNOS.NOME, DISCIPLINAS.NOME AS DISCIPLINA, MAX(NOTAS.NOTA) AS MEDIA FROM NOTAS
INNER JOIN ALUNO_DISCIPLINA ON ALUNO_DISCIPLINA.identificacao = NOTAS.codAlunoDisciplina
INNER JOIN DISCIPLINAS ON ALUNO_DISCIPLINA.CODIGO_DISCIPLINA = DISCIPLINAS.CODIGO
INNER JOIN ALUNOS ON ALUNO_DISCIPLINA.registro_aluno = ALUNOS.Registro
GROUP BY DISCIPLINAS.NOME,ALUNOS.NOME
ORDER BY DISCIPLINAS.NOME
```

Aí o resultado gera a seguinte tabela conforme a imagem[image: Tabela]

Gostaria que mostrasse somente (MARIA geografia 9,00) e (JOÃO portugues 10,00),que são as maiores notas dos alunos, ou seja comparar entre português e mostrar a maior nota tbm. Alguma sugestão onde estou errando??

Comment: Qual SGBD você está utilizando?

Comment: sql server management studio 2014

Comment: @Abism sua pergunta não está clara... você precisa do aluno que tirou a maior nota por disciplina? Deve ser considerada a média ou somente a nota? E se existirem alunos com as mesmas notas, traz os dois? Como você é novo por aqui sugiro que leia [mcve].

Comment: Olha Mateus, não tinha pensado por esse lado, se tivesse alunos com mesma nota na mesma matéria!! Porém o correto seria retornar o aluno,disciplina e a maior nota na matéria, se tivesse outro aluno com a mesma nota tbm traria ele na tabela, por isso estou usando o MAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder fazer o que você precisa, você pode utilizar a função `RANK` desta forma:

```
WITH resumo AS (SELECT
                    A.Nome NomeAluno,
                    D.Nome NomeDisciplina,
                    MAX(N.Nota) MaiorNota,
                    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY D.Nome ORDER BY MAX(N.Nota) DESC)  Posicao
                FROM ALUNOS A
                    INNER JOIN ALUNO_DISCIPLINA AD ON (A.Registro = AD.registro_aluno)
                    INNER JOIN DISCIPLINAS D ON (AD.CODIGO_DISCIPLINA = D.CODIGO)
                    INNER JOIN NOTAS N ON (AD.identificacao = N.codAlunoDisciplina)
                GROUP BY
                    A.Nome,
                    D.Nome)

SELECT 
    r.NomeAluno,
    r.NomeDisciplina,
    r.MaiorNota
FROM 
    resumo r 
WHERE 
    r.Posicao = 1
ORDER BY
    r.NomeDisciplina,
    r.NomeAluno;
```

O `PARTITION BY` divide os dados pelo nome da disciplina e o `ORDER BY DESC` ordena da maior nota para a menor, dessa forma, se existirem mesmas notas para alunos diferentes na mesma disciplina, irão aparece todos os alunos. O `WITH` serve para você pode dar nome a um resutado e utilizá-lo em seguida, conforme eu fiz.

**Referências:**

[RANK (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql)
[WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql)

Comment: Deu certo. Deixou bem explícito o que era para ser feito. Entendi a explicação

Answer (score 0):

Não tenho como testar aqui, mas acredito que o que vc precisa é de uma subquery, `SELECT FROM SELECT`, teste ai e me diga se funciona (pode ser que tenha que fazer algum ajuste):

```
SELECT NOME, DISCIPLINA, MAX(MEDIA) AS MEDIA FROM 
    (SELECT ALUNOS.NOME, DISCIPLINAS.NOME AS DISCIPLINA, MAX(NOTAS.NOTA) AS MEDIA FROM
        NOTAS
        INNER JOIN ALUNO_DISCIPLINA ON ALUNO_DISCIPLINA.identificacao = NOTAS.codAlunoDisciplina
        INNER JOIN DISCIPLINAS ON ALUNO_DISCIPLINA.CODIGO_DISCIPLINA = DISCIPLINAS.CODIGO
        INNER JOIN ALUNOS ON ALUNO_DISCIPLINA.registro_aluno = ALUNOS.Registro
        GROUP BY DISCIPLINAS.NOME,ALUNOS.NOME
        ORDER BY DISCIPLINAS.NOME) 
GROUP BY DISCIPLINA
```

Comment: Meu amigo testei e mesmo modificando, não tava aceitando retornar vários valores da segunda query.

Comment: A segunda query é a sua propria. O que fiz foi um select do seu select. [Veja esse link.](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/22319.986018311@sss.pgh.pa.us) ou [esse.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_sub_queries.htm)